# Compile Delphi unit with SSE (fma)

Tags: delphi, sse, freepascal

In Free-Pascal you can determine if the code is compiled using SSE2/3/64 instructions via the conditional defines from 
https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/prog/prog.html#QQ2-333-379, 
Table G.3: Possible FPU defines when compiling using FPC

```
FPUSSE2   SSE 2 instructions on Intel I386 and higher. 
FPUSSE3   SSE 3 instructions on Intel I386 and higher, AMD64.
FPUSSE64  SSE64 FPU on Intel I386 and higher, AMD64.
```

I know the Delphi 64-bit compilers use SSE in the Win RTL, but my question is:

> Is there a known method in Delphi to check at **compile time**, if a unit is compiled with SSE instructions, especially if `a*b + c` is computed with hardware fma instructions?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a known method in Delphi to check at compile time, if a unit is compiled with SSE instructions?

On Intel platforms, if the `CPUX64` conditional is defined then the compiler generates floating point code using SSE instructions. Otherwise, x87 instructions are generated.

No Delphi compiler generates code using FMA instructions. The floating point codegen used by dcc64 has not changed materially since its initial release in XE2.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately at least Delphi 17/18 do seem to not use fma in
`function fma_d(a,b,c: double): double; inline;  begin fma_d := a*b + c; end;`

Comment: No Delphi compiler generates code with such instructions. Codegen hasn't changed significantly  since XE2.

Comment: Yes it generates those instructions: `mulsd xmm0,xmm1` and `addsd xmm0,xmm2` (for me this does not look like fma). But with this
I get for my test suite with D18 following errors 
**RMS = 2.11, max rel = 207.87 eps**, with my software solution
I have **RMS = 0.21, max rel = 0.50 eps**, and FPC gives
**RMS = 0.02, max rel = 0.48 eps**

Comment: I don't know what you want me to say. Delphi isn't going to generate FMA instructions. Why do you think it will?

Comment: What is D17 or D18? Please use the commonly used names. I see no reason why you can't use those, instead of some obscure version number.

Comment: @rudy-velthuis: See the column Product Version at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Compiler_Versions.

Comment: @gammatester: Why do you force others to do that? If you want to ask a question, don't force others to research things you can easily post. In other words: make it easier for the people answering, so they are more inclined to help you. So, for a product, use the usual names, not some obscure version number that people must first look up to know what you are talking about.